# NameError: uninitialized constant User on irb console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When writing `User.all`

However I don't get this error when using rails c

I have only two models:

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord  
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable,
         :validatable   
  has_many :items
end
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord   
  belongs_to :user 
end
```

My Gemfile includes:

```
gem 'devise'
```

I've checked the models and controller names (singular and plural), and restarted the console. I've tried running `spring stop` and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Where is your code calling User.new? Where is your require/load for user.rb? Why are you tryin* to run Rails code outside of a Rails console?

Comment: Do you run `rails console`?

Comment: @MrFacundo : In your posting, you say under what conditions you **do not get** the error, but you do not specify exactly under what conditions you **do get** the error.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs my code calling User.new is opening the irb console, which is the console I usually use on my projects,  writing User.all and hitting Enter, that's all. When I do that, I get the message error. If however I type User.all in rails console, then I don't get the error

Answer (score 1):

`rails c` is the intended way to open a console for your app. It loads rails itself, all your models and everything else needed.

You could require all the components yourself by calling `require_relative 'config/environment'` in irb, but `rails c` is just easier.

Just use `rails console` instead of `irb`.

Comment: Thanks. So far I had only used irb console, I didn't know of rails console until researching about this message error. But Ill use that one from now on.

Answer (score 0):

### IRB REPL vs. Rails Console

If you invoke `irb` from the command line, you don't get a prompt inside a Rails application; you just get a REPL without any of your Rails objects. In your case, *User* is a Rails model. It is not available in a plain irb session, unless you first require/load Users.rb and all its dependencies inside the irb session.

Instead, invoke `rails console` (`rails c` for short) to provide a Rails-powered irb session. The Rails console will take care of loading and initializing the Ruby on Rails core, the various gems declared in your Gemfile, and your custom Rails objects such as models and helpers.

Once the User class has been properly loaded or required, User will be a valid object. You can do this manually in irb if you thoroughly understand the [Rails initialization process](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html), but invoking the Rails console is both simpler and less error-prone.